# PHP SDK : Login API not working

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am using PHP SDK from Facebook for integrating Facebook login to my website. The system is prompting for Facebook Login. However, the FB session variables are not once the FB login is successful.

In particular :`$_SESSION['fb_token']` is not set

```
$session = $helper->getSessionFromRedirect(); is NULL
```

Any idea, if I am missing anything ?

Here is the code I am using :

```
session_start();
require_once('includes/facebook/src/Facebook/HttpClients/FacebookHttpable.php');
require_once('includes/facebook/src/Facebook/HttpClients/FacebookCurl.php');
require_once('includes/facebook/src/Facebook/HttpClients/FacebookCurlHttpClient.php');

require_once('includes/facebook/src/Facebook/Entities/AccessToken.php');
require_once('includes/facebook/src/Facebook/Entities/SignedRequest.php');

require_once('includes/facebook/src/Facebook/FacebookSession.php');
require_once('includes/facebook/src/Facebook/FacebookRedirectLoginHelper.php');
require_once('includes/facebook/src/Facebook/FacebookRequest.php');
require_once('includes/facebook/src/Facebook/FacebookResponse.php');
require_once('includes/facebook/src/Facebook/FacebookSDKException.php');
require_once('includes/facebook/src/Facebook/FacebookRequestException.php');
require_once('includes/facebook/src/Facebook/FacebookOtherException.php');
require_once('includes/facebook/src/Facebook/FacebookAuthorizationException.php');
require_once('includes/facebook/src/Facebook/GraphObject.php');
require_once('includes/facebook/src/Facebook/GraphSessionInfo.php');



use Facebook\HttpClients\FacebookHttpable;
use Facebook\HttpClients\FacebookCurl;
use Facebook\HttpClients\FacebookCurlHttpClient;

use Facebook\Entities\AccessToken;
use Facebook\Entities\SignedRequest;

use Facebook\FacebookSession;
use Facebook\FacebookRedirectLoginHelper;
use Facebook\FacebookRequest;
use Facebook\FacebookResponse;
use Facebook\FacebookSDKException;
use Facebook\FacebookRequestException;
use Facebook\FacebookOtherException;
use Facebook\FacebookAuthorizationException;
use Facebook\GraphObject;
use Facebook\GraphSessionInfo;


$app_id = get_config('facebook_app_id');
$app_secret = get_config('facebook_secret_key');

FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication($app_id, $app_secret);

$redirect_url = 'http://mywebsite.com/home.php?msg_ok=Thanks';

$helper = new FacebookRedirectLoginHelper($redirect_url);


// see if a existing session exists
if ( isset( $_SESSION ) && isset( $_SESSION['fb_token'] ) ) {
    // create new session from saved access_token
    $session = new FacebookSession( $_SESSION['fb_token'] );

    // validate the access_token to make sure it's still valid
    try {
        if ( !$session->validate() ) {
            $session = null;
        }
    } catch ( Exception $e ) {
        // catch any exceptions
        $session = null;
    }
}  

if ( !isset( $session ) || $session === null ) {
    // no session exists

    try 
    {
        $session = $helper->getSessionFromRedirect();
    } 
    catch( FacebookRequestException $ex ) 
    {
        // When Facebook returns an error
        // handle this better in production code
        print_r( $ex );
    } catch( Exception $ex ) {
        // When validation fails or other local issues
        // handle this better in production code
        print_r( $ex );
    }

}


// see if we have a session
if ( isset( $session ) ) {


    // save the session
    $_SESSION['fb_token'] = $session->getToken();
    // create a session using saved token or the new one we generated at login
    $session = new FacebookSession( $session->getToken() );

    // graph api request for user data
    $request = new FacebookRequest( $session, 'GET', '/me');
    $response = $request->execute();

    // get response
    $graphObject = $response->getGraphObject()->asArray();

    var_dump($graphObject);

    // print profile data
    echo '<pre>'. print_r( $graphObject, 1 ) . '</pre>';

    // print logout url using session and redirect_uri (logout.php page should destroy the session)
    echo '<a href="'. $helper->getLogoutUrl( $session, $redirect_url ) . '">Logout</a>';

} 
else 
{
    // show login url
    //$scope = array('email,publish_stream,user_birthday,user_photos,friends_photos','user_friends');
    $scope = array('email','user_friends');
    //echo '<a href="'. $helper->getLoginUrl( array( 'email', 'user_friends') ) . '">Login</a>';
    echo '<a href="'. $helper->getLoginUrl($scope) . '">Login</a>';
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just now wrote simple facebook api snippet which will help you to understand the Facebook API.

Try the below code first and then understand the code, inline comments will help you. And make sure before running the code to download the SDK using `composer` and also add your `Facebook Application` details.

**Here's the code:**

```
// Starting the session
session_start();

// Including composer autoload file..make sure to alter directory address according to you
include_once "vendor/autoload.php";

// Facebook App Configs
define("FB_APP_ID", "YOUR_FB_APP_ID_HERE");
define("FB_APP_SECRET", "YOUR_FB_APP_SECRET_HERE");
define("FB_APP_REDIRECT", "YOUR_FB_REDIRECT_URL_HERE");

// Setting details default app & redirect URL
Facebook\FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication(FB_APP_ID, FB_APP_SECRET);
$fb = new Facebook\FacebookRedirectLoginHelper(FB_APP_REDIRECT);


// Trying to get user token
try {
    if($session = $fb->getSessionFromRedirect()) {
        $_SESSION["fb_token"] = $session->getToken();
        header("Location: index.php");
        exit(0);
    }
} catch(Facebook\FacebookRequestException $e) {
    die($e->getMessage());
} catch(\Exception $e) {
    die($e->getMessage());
}

// Using token which is stored in local Session.
if(isset($_SESSION['fb_token'])) {
    // Getting user session with Token
    $uSession = new Facebook\FacebookSession($_SESSION['fb_token']);

// Making a graph API request
$user = (new Facebook\FacebookRequest(
    $uSession, 'GET', '/me'
))->execute()
  ->getGraphObject(Facebook\GraphUser::className())->asArray();

  // print_r($user);

echo <<<userProfile
    <table>
        <tbody>
userProfile;

foreach($user as $key => $value) {
    echo <<<userProfile
        <tr>
            <td>{$key}</td>
            <td>{$value}</td>
        </tr>
userProfile;
}

echo <<<userProfile
    </tbody>
</table>
<a href="?logout">Logout</a>
<hr />
userProfile;
}


// Settings scope/permissions
$login_url = $fb->getLoginUrl(array(
    'scope' => 'user_birthday,user_about_me,user_website,read_stream,publish_stream,publish_actions,manage_pages,email,user_checkins',
));

// Login link
if(!isset($_SESSION["fb_token"])) {
    echo '<a href="' . $login_url . '">Login with Facebook</a>';
}

// Logout code block
if(isset($_SESSION["fb_token"], $_GET['logout'])) {
    unset($_SESSION['fb_token']);
    header("Location: index.php");
    exit(0);
}
```

Also for reference you can check out the docs: [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/gettingstarted/4.0.0)
And you can also check a video tutorial on working with Facebook API: [here](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLfdtiltiRHWF3PB8_djMEcvwyj8SWHLda)

Comment: Thanks Ashwin, Even though, I did not use your exact code, It did help my understanding of the API integration.